# Change of coordinates

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hi everyone!

Can someone explain me this exercice? My solution was $\theta\in [\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}]\cup[\frac{5\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{2})$, which is incorrect, but I can't understand why...

The other parts were correct.

I thought $x \leq y \Leftrightarrow r\cdot\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi) \le r\cdot \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) \Leftrightarrow 1 \le \operatorname{tg}(\theta)$ so $\theta \in [\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}]\cup[\frac{5\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{2})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot that dividing (and multiplying) an **inequality** by some number requires **checking the sign of the divisor** (or factor), in order to find out if the **inequality changes the direction**.

That's because from $a \le b$ it surely does not follow $-a \le -b$, the opppsite is true: $a \le b \Leftrightarrow -a \ge -b$.

That doesn't affect the common factor $\sin(\phi)$, as that is non-negative for $0 \le \phi < \pi$. But $\cos(\theta)$ changes signs at $\theta=\frac{\pi}2,\frac{3\pi}2$. That means when you divide by it to get the inequality involving $\tan(\theta)$ you need to consider 2 cases:

1) $\cos(\theta) \ge 0$, or $\theta \in [0,{\pi \over 2}] \cup [{3\pi \over 2},{2\pi})$. Your correct solution set for $\tan(\theta) \ge 1$ needs then be restricted to the given interval of $\theta$, which gives $I_1(\theta)=[{\pi \over 4},{\pi \over 2}]$.

2) $\cos(\theta) < 0$, or $\theta \in ({\pi \over 2}, {3\pi \over 2})$. In that interval, then the inequality becomes $\tan(\theta) \le 1$. The solution set of this, restricted to $({\pi \over 2}, {3\pi \over 2})$ is $I_2(\theta)=({\pi \over 2},{5\pi \over 4}]$.

Finally, the possible set for $\theta$ is $I_1(\theta) \cup I_2(\theta) = [{\pi \over 4},{5\pi \over 4}]$, as given in the book.

So the main thing to remember is that **multiplying/dividing an inequality requires extra steps** to get the correct direction of the inequality!

Comment: Thank you for the answer!